# Unable to find a bootable option

Tags: lumia-520, recovery-tool

When I start up my Lumia 520, it displays an error saying "Unable to find a bootable option". I've tried to recover it using Windows Phone Recovery Tool, but now my phone says "The software is not correctly signed or not signed for this phone".

What else can I try to fix it?

Comment: Did you downloaded latest package using recovery tool?

Comment: When did this issue first occur? When you bought the phone or did you try to update it?

Comment: yes.I had downloaded it.But when installing it that error occures.

Comment: N K-yes I downloded

Comment: Thomas_it occured at last wednesday,I bought phone on 08,Janury 2014 & updated it on 03 june 2015

Comment: I suspect that it should be the problem with ROM may be. You may have to replace the hardware. Please consider any other solutions before this.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem once but was able to solve it using the [Windows Device Recovery Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987) - make sure always you download the latest ROM version for your device.

If this doesn't work then your only option is to contact the manufacturers service.

Comment: manufacturer says your phone wont be able to repair .what should i do now???